# Stop PhpStorm from automatically staging deleted files to git

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

If I delete a file in PhpStorm it is automatically staged in git. I would like to do the staging by hand (git add/rm) when ever I am ready.

How can I prevent PhpStorm from automatically stage files if I delete them in PhpStorm?

Like if I delete the files anywhere else it works correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The option is under `Settings > Version Control > Confirmation`. You can configure the behavior for adding and deleting files independently.

- When `Add/remove silently` is selected, git add/rm is staged automatically.
- `Do not add/remove` is the option you are looking for.
- Select `Show options before adding/removing from version control` to decide each time whether PhpStorm should stage the change.

Comment: Thank you! I had the option `Show options before adding/removing from version control` but there was never options showing after deleting a file.. anyway setting it to `Do not add/remove` was exactly what I was looking for! thanks